# Why adding another LOOKUP transformation slows down performance significantly SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, lookup

I have a simple SSIS package that transfer data between source and destination from one server to another.

If its new records  - it inserts, otherwise it checks `HashByteValue` column and if it different its update record.

Table contains approx 1.5 million rows, and updates around 50 columns.

When I start debug the package, for around 2 minutes nothing happens, I cant even see the green check-mark. After that I can see data starts flowing through, but sometimes it stops, then flowing again, then stops again and so on.

The whole package looks like this:

[image]

But if I do just `INSERT` part (without update) then it works perfectly, 1 min and all 1.5 million records in a destination table.

[image]

So why adding another `LOOKUP` transformation to the package that updates records slows down performance so significantly. 
Is it something to do with memory? I am using `FULL CACHE` option in both `lookups`.

what would be the way to increase performance?

Can the reason be in Auto Growth File size:

[image]

Comment: When in doubt, trace!

Comment: Increase your Autogrowth for Data and Log to 100MB, and see if that helps.  1MB is way too small.  Rarely should you ever use default 10 percent for Autogrowth.

Comment: I have edited my post. You can see the Auto Growth of the database. Thanks

Comment: Yes, sorry, I accidentally removed my original comment about AutoGrowth.  But it appears that can be part of your problem, for sure.

Comment: When you run the package, check the progress tab -- is it sitting on the pre-execute stage?  It's most likely a delay caused by the pre-fetching of the destination data you are going to update.  It has to load them into memory before it can compare them to your source data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides changing AutoGrowth size to 100MB, your Database Log file is 29GB.  That means you most likely are not doing Transaction Log backups.

If you're not, and only do Full Backups nightly or periodically.  Change the Recovery Model of your Database from Full to Simple.

Database Properties > Options > Recovery Model

Then Shrink your Log file down to 100MB using:

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE(Catalytic_Log, 100)
```

Comment: You are right. We just created this new instance on a different server and none of us really know how properly set everything up. Thanks

Comment: I edited above, showing you how to shrink your Log file down after setting to Simple.

Comment: Much Much Much Much Much Much Much better!!!!  
Still waits a little bit before starting flowing data, but then everything done with less than 2 minutes!!
Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that your problem is in the lookup. The OLE DB Command is realy slow on SSIS and I don't think it is meant for a massive update of rows. Look at this answer in the MSDN: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4f1a62e2-50c7-4d22-9ce9-a9b3d12fd7ce/improve-data-load-perfomance-in-oledb-command?forum=sqlintegrationservices

To verify that the error is not the lookup, try disabling the "OLE DB Command" and rerun the process and see how long it takes.

In my personal experience it is always better to create a Stored procedure to do the whole "dataflow" when you have to update or insert based on certain conditions. To do that you would need a Staging table and a Destination table (where you are going to load the transformed data).

Hope it helps.

Comment: **I don't know why this answer got a down-vote - it actually answered the question.**  The backup response by Gordon Bell (while completely true) is on a tangent.  OLEDB cmd does a row-by-row insert, oledb destination, set to fast load does a comparatively faster "bulk" load.  Instead of the cmd, you should do as asemprini87 suggested and direct the update rows to a staging table, then call a proc to run the update.

Comment: Could you please correct me if I am wrong...So I have source table and destination table. What you saying is I should  redirect rows that matched on ID to the third (staging) table. Then use SP to update them?

Comment: Usually ETL processes use a standard where you throw the query into the data source and the result is put into a Staging Table. Once you have the data in Stage, you run the Transformation process to put it into the DataWarehouse. In this step is where you should have the SP to do this Insertions and update. We use staging tables for this purpose specially on big processes:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staging_(data)